# What plugin is used to create the user card and tag pop-ups?

Tags: support, user-interface

What jQuery plugin is used to display the user card and tag information pop-ups? I was convinced one of the team posted details about the implementation before but my google and SO searching skills are failing me today.

I am considering implementing a similar feature for a in-house project and I am looking for a starting point.

Comment: Note that if you'd ask for the same effect on SO, you'd have a complete working fiddle in minutes.

Comment: @dystroy Correct. But I didn't want a working fiddle :) I wanted to determine if I needed to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could delve into the code and see, it's not using any plugin just custom code and ordinary jQuery animation.

The function used is called `MagicPopup`, it's part of the full JavaScript code used in the site and is [publicly available](http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js).

Comment: I suspected as much, I suspect the plugin I am referring to is something else one of the developers referred to once before.